# Flex Mojo Maven Compile Question

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am trying to get the flex mojos maven compiler to run my projects.

Anyone with feedback on the below information is appreciated.

I am using this configuration for the maven compiler plugin and for
some reason every time I run the clean install on my SWF project I
still see the following in the compile step for the app.

info.rvin.mojo
                                        flex-compiler-mojo
                                        true
                                        
                                                true

-compiler.accessible=false
-compiler.actionscript-file-encoding UTF-8
-compiler.allow-source-path-overlap=false
-compiler.as3=true
-compiler.debug=false

That means I can not connect to my app via the Flex Builder's debug
tool. Any thoughts on how I should properly configure the plugin in
the pom.xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

adam, we're just starting to build out the [chapter on flexmojos in Maven: The Definitive Guide](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/ch20.html).   For starters, use the new plugin groupId, artifactId that is listed in that chapter.  velo moved the flexmojos project over to the Sonatype Forge a few months ago, and we're just getting the 3.0 release out.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone out there reading this: remember Maven is a build tool; it only (typically) executes (parts of) your code as a consequence of executing the tests you've implemented.